# Using the user_username instead of user_id to access a user profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

How can I access a model object by their username instead of their id or how can I convert the username into an id that can then be used to access a model object?

I have a view like below where the argument that is being passed in is the user_username:

**views.py**

```
def profile_page(request, user_username):
    form = FollowUserForm(request)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_username)
    return render(request, "network/profilePage.html", {
        "form": form,
        "profile": profile
    })
```

I know that we can't put the user equal to user_username so is there a way of converting the username somehow into an id which I can then use to access the relevant Profile object? I'm doing it like this because in my urls.py I want the url to show the user's username rather than just a number id.

**urls.py**

```
path("profile/<str:user_username>", views.profile_page, name="profile"),
```

Edited to add:

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name='following', blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on the `username` of the user with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def profile_page(request, user_username):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=user_username)
    form = FollowUserForm(request)
    return render(request, 'network/profilePage.html', {
        'form': form,
        'profile': profile
    })
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.